# C# asynchronous socket BeginSend EndReceive

Tags: c#, sockets

I am new to programming and I am confused about asynchronous socket programming.

For example let's say I have two `BeginSend`s, one right after another. The first sends a million chars and the second sends only 64 chars.

Due to the asynchronous nature won't the second `BeginSend` complete before the first one?

If so how can I tell the recieved data at `EndRecieve`, belongs to which message?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You really shouldn't call two BeginSend's after one another.
I think that you'll end up seeing exceptions thrown if this happens.

You have to call an EndSend before calling another BeginSend. This is typically done in side the callback function.

Check out the example [Using an Asynchronous Client Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8.aspx) at MSDN. In the callback the EndSend is called, and then a ManualResetEvent called "sendDone" is set. This is a form of inter-thread communication in which the callback is signaling to your main thread that the asynchronous send is completed. This then allows your program to cue up the next piece of data.

- Call BeginSend from your main thread to send the first 1,000,000 bytes
- Your main thread can check on a semaphore or something like the ManualResetEvent to trigger it to send the next 64 bytes. Your other option is to use a queue for the data to send
- When the data has finished sending, the callback you passed in to the BeginSend will be called.
- In this call back, you will call EndSend. Follow this then setting the ManualResetEvent, or what ever inter-thread trigger you wish to use.

The simplest option, which I recall doing once, is to call BeginSend for the next piece of data in the callback for the first piece of data being done.

e.g.

```
int NumBytesSent; // member variable containing how many bytes you have sent so far
string Message;   // Message to send that is large
```

When you call BeginSend, pass in a chunk of say 100 bytes (pick a larger number for more efficient transfers, but not too large) to send and increment NumBytesSend by 100.
Next, in your callback for the previous send being completed you can check if NumBytesSent < Message.Length, and if it is then send the next chunk of the Message.

This is how you would send a file you send a bunch of bytes at once, and just keep sending chunks of the file until it is all sent.

I highly recommend making a simple client/server to do something like sending a complete file over a connection. Also review the MSDN documents and the many other examples out and about in the web.

Getting a good grip on this will help you with lots of other C# topics as working asynchronously (or using delegates/callbacks) is very common for .NET

Comment: thanks Mark, thats always the way I build my network code.
I've done this stuff MANY MANY times, but always start with a generic simple start point and work up from there.

Comment: Could some one explain what they mean by: It assumes a global ManualResetEvent named connectDone.

Comment: @Eidenai The examples on the MSDN site don't provide all the required member or global variables for the example. In this case they are assuming that you have a variable somewhere accessible of type ManualResetEvent that is named connectDone so that they can use it for inter thread communication with connectDone.WaitOne() and connectDone.Set(). This variable needs to be in a place that is accessible by both threads

Answer (score 1):

The [BeginSend method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.beginsend%28VS.71%29.aspx) includes a parameter `AsyncCallback callback`. If you use two different callbacks, you can see which one completed first.

But if you are trying to send both messages on the same connection, you will have problems. You should wait until the first message is completely sent before sending the second.

Comment: I think the sending will probably work, but I suspect that the messages will become interleaved and unparseable.

Comment: that the issue. how do i avoid that? it can be done because applications like mirc deal with these kind of issues all the time. i would like to know how can i implement it?

Comment: waiting until first message is completely sent? i should have code in EndSend to check for completion of the first message?

Comment: Yes. You don't need "code in EndSend to check for completion of the first message". When you get the callback, it means the Send has completed.

Comment: thanks Fuzz, you have mentioned a good point. im not sure of this behaviour. i am just trying to clear up doubt before coding.

Comment: Mark: what i mean is setting a flag in BeginSend that message is begin sent. and in EndSend i modify it to state message has been sent. and then if any messages that have queued up, send them next.

Comment: @Fuzz: you might be right, the best way to determine this is to try it. @ikurtz: you can start the next BeginSend in the body of your asynchronous callback function. You don't need a separate flag - you can just check if the queue is empty or not.

Comment: "Your callback method should invoke the EndSend method. When your application calls BeginSend, the system will use a separate thread to execute the specified callback method, and will block on EndSend until the Socket sends the number of bytes requested or throws an exception." from MSDN

Yes Mark, I believe that is correct with respect to calling the next BeginSend from the call back