# (Async) Sending data to multiple clients correctly

Tags: c#, asynchronous

If I understood the logic of BeginSend correctly:

```
private void sendToClient(Client client, String data)
{
    byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data); //It must be UTF8

    client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0, 
                     new AsyncCallback(sendCallback), client);
}
private void sendCallback(IAsyncResult iar)
{
    Socket client = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
    int bytesSent = client.EndSend(iar);
}
```

I have sent the data to one client correctly.

But if I want to send the data for more clients:

```
/**
 * I am using dictionary, because I hold the clients with login-key
 */
private void SendToClients(Dictionary<string, Client> connectedClients, String data)
{ 
    foreach(Client client in connectedClients.Values)
    {
        sendToClient(client, data);
    }
}
```

Or in anotherway, I can use SocketAsyncEventArgs to send all clients:

```
private void sendToClients(Dictionary<string, Client> connectedClients, String data)
{
    SocketAsyncEventArgs asyncEvent;
    byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data); //It must be UTF8

    lock (connectedClients)
    {
        foreach (Client client in connectedClients.Values)
        {
            try
            {
                asyncEvent = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
                asyncEvent.SetBuffer(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
                client.Socket.SendAsync(asyncEvent);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //ERROR.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But both **sendToClients** methods work slow for me and/or sometimes server can't send the data to the *any* client. The packet can be lost.

**Example:**

Client1 Received 103 packets

Client2 Received 107 packets

Client3 Received 102 packets

Clientn Received 106 packets

But it should be 111 packets at the end.

Is there another methods/logics/technologies to send one data to more then one client or is there something used wrong in my examples?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code looks ok, but it depends on the calling code initiating the multiple send calls. Note that you can't safely call `BeginSend` multiple times before each previous operation has finished. See here:
[Async Socket Writes - Potential for send operations to get mixed up? (.NET Sockets)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897712/async-socket-writes-potential-for-send-operations-to-get-mixed-up-net-socke). This may explain your non-deterministic packet received counts. So if you want to go that approach, you should probably use some mechanism that prevents multiple `BeginSend` calls before previous ones have finished.

But what I have been doing lately is using the new TPL and its `Task.Factory.FromAsync` method to convert the old APM style Begin/End X to a `Task<T>`:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/06/09/9716439.aspx

Once you have the Task object it is simple to schedule the next send (without overlapping the previous) by using the `Task.ContinueWith' method.

Comment: Do you mean something like: Task<bool>.Factory.FromAsync( 
    stream.BeginSend, stream.EndSend, buffer, 0, buffer.Length, client); i set bool to check, if its complated

Comment: Yes, and no. Your FromAsync socket call looks good. But don't use a separate bool, the task has a IsCompleted property. But really, you shouldn't care anymore if it's completed or not, as your just scheduling new tasks to run once it's finished by using the `ContinueWith` method. The underlying task will do all the checks and scheduling for you.

Comment: Thank you Tyson, I am testing it now.